# Novel about hyper-intelligent children

Tags: story-identification, novel

Does anyone know the title of this sci-fi novel I read around the year 2000?

The story opens in a facility where hyper-intelligent children are being raised. The central character is the ‘runt’ of the litter, but he is still a genius.

He escapes from the facility and flees to India where he hides with a poor Indian woman. He is able to pass on his genetically engineered genes through his saliva, so when he kisses the Indian woman his genes for intelligence begin to spread through the population.

Soon, most humans are hyper-intelligent.  The story then moves into space, where two factions battle it out over whether to construct some kind of engineering project.

Answer (score 9):

This is **[Centuries](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1604502835)** by [A. A. Attanasio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._A._Attanasio).

Comment: Thank you, timbp. You've identified it for me. I lost the book years ago and have been trying to recall its title ever since.

Comment: @Ian, please mark the answer as the correct answer then.

Comment: @Ian, please mark this answer correct to help other people, in addition to the one that answered it.